# Pattern for an enum-like class with many different types / constructors

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I am working with a communication standard (over which I have no control) that defines data items to be sent/received in various packets.

**Each item is defined by a custom type, and *type-dependent* information. These items will rarely change.  I'd like to be able to limit the scope of item constructors to one place, and define all items there once as `public static` (similar to an enum)**.

Currently, I have an enum for the types, and a class for the items.

```
enum Type {TYPE_A, TYPE_B, ...}

public class Item {
    public static Item ITEM_1 = new Item(TYPE_A, someNumber);
    public static Item ITEM_2 = new Item(TYPE_B, someNumber, someMap);
    public static Item ITEM_3 = new Item(TYPE_A, someNumber);
    ...

    // Constructor for type A
    private Item(Type type, int param1) {...}

    // Constructor for type B
    private Item(Type type, int param1, Map param2) {...}

    ...

    // Type-dependent methods
    public String decode(byte[] data) {
        switch(this.type) {
        case TYPE_A:
            ...
        }
        case TYPE_B:
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**This has become unmanageable, and I am looking for a better pattern / structure.**

I could have an abstract Item class, and subclass for each type.  With this setup, I don't know how I could define all the items in one place without making all the constructors public.

Comment: Why don't you use `enum`s? Enums can have fields, methods and constructors.

Comment: Making the `Item` class an `Enum` is a good suggestion. But this does not fully solve the problem.  I'll still have 20+ constructors... one for each enum constant.

Comment: @firyice Can you use varargs to combine them all?

Comment: @PeterLawrey It *could* be done, but I do not think varargs makes sense here. The type-dependent parameters in each constructor vary in nature.

Comment: @firyice Instead of multiple constructors you can use multiple factory methods. This would make sure the type matches the arguments used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instances don't *have* different types, they *are* different types.

Step 1: Delete your enum entirely.

Step 2: Create an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Item {
    public abstract String decode(byte[] data);
    // other common stuff
}
```

Step: Create subclasses for each type that provide implementations for the decode method:

```
public class ItemType1 extends Item {
    public String decode(byte[] data) {
        // implementation for this type
    }
}
```

Any time you find yourself using a case or instanceof to decide which code to run, consider breaking out new classes that override the method. This is all straightforward class hierarchy stuff.

---

#### Edit:

If you wanted to use an enum to self-document the range of types available, you could do this:

```
enum Type {
    TYPE_A () {
        public Item createItem() {
            return new ItemType1();
        }
    },
    TYPE_B () {
        public Item createItem() {
            return new ItemType2();
        }
    },
    ...;
    public abstract Item createItem();
}
```

Comment: "Your instances don't *have* different types, they *are* different types." thanks for the 'Aha!' moment.  Exactly what I needed to hear.  I decided to use this approach along with [Ghostkeeper's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19202693/884677) for enforcing scope.

Comment: You might consider the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory) - see edit to answer for something I think you will like

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to use the abstract class structure, like you described: An abstract item class, and subclasses for each type.

However, since you have that many different types, I suggest you put them in a separate package, and then make the constructors of the subclasses package-local. That way you can all construct them in the static section of the abstract class, while still protecting external code from trying to construct an item.